# "Send as" permissions for all (public) addresses

Tags: exchange-2010, email

We need to find a solution to the following scenario: We are introducing a ticket system and need to redirect mails the support desk is receiving (50% internal, 50% external) to this ticket system but KEEP the original Mail address.

There is a feature in Outlook which is called "resend message", but we are not able to use it because we have no "send as"-Permissions for this external mail addresses.

Of course, we could iterate through all internal accounts and add send-as permissions for the ticket administrators and add e-mail contacts for every external mail address but our goal is to save some time.

**Note**: Currently the users and external contacts also write to the employees personal mail addresses. So the the employees want to forward the mails and keep the original senders mailaddress in order to make the ticketing system recognize the originator of an incident.

Answer (score 2):

The proper solution to this problem (that you clarified in the comments) is to create a central email address for people to email, and point the ticketing system at that.  Something along the lines of `helpdesk@[company].com` or `ITproblems@[company].com`, etc. Then technicians grab issues out of the queue and work them, or close them for lacking information, or what have you.  I've even seen this approach work effectively with a shared mailbox.

Having users email individual technicians and then having the technicians forward those emails into the system is the *wrong*™ way to approach this.

Comment: We already introduced a central email address but a lot of customers are still using the personal mail addresses. To also forward these mails to the ticket mail address we need the "resend mail" feature.

Comment: There is no solution to that other than educating users / customers, OR change the e-mail address once it arrived in the ticketing system. See my answer.

Comment: @Wolfgang Well, that's a people problem.  You're not going to be able to `send as` an external user, because, well, security.  Fix the problem by educating your users and/or customers, not trying to solve the problem of people sending to the wrong email address.

Comment: A hybrid approach would be great to (a) educate the user (b) give the users some time to learn :)

Comment: @Wolfgang "Dear user, [blah] is the new email address. You have as much time to learn the new email address as it will take me to walk over to your desk and beat you into a coma with my keyboard for emailing the wrong email address."

Answer (score 1):

I think this is nothing you can solve "technically", as you're not allowed to "send as another user" in exchange (well, under certain circumstances you are - other story)

This is a problem of user education. Your technicians should ideally tell the customer that they need to use another e-mail address, and that they cannot process it this way OR they need to forward it, and then change the user in the ticketing system.

Comment: That's exactly the problem - we are working on the education but we can't force customers to use a new mail address because this will certainly annoy them. I know that it is possible in postfix to achieve this desired behaviour, but it may also be possible in exchange...

Comment: It is not possible in exchange in a "reasonable" manner. Giving everyone send-permissions to everything is just not reasonable for me. Preventing users from "impersonating" others is a feature, not a "bug", so postfix actually lacks this "feature" in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply configure Exchange to [forward](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281926) emails for the support desk to your ticketing system and keep the emails in both mailboxes.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that users also write to the employees personal mail addresses we can't forward.